# How can I control my versioning (perhaps with GIT), such that when I update a function (such as add an argument) it won't break the rest of the code?

Tags: version-control, git, github, gitflow, matlab

I'm just working on a set of MATLAB files right now that I'm using for my thesis. I want to be better organized and figure out the best way to keep track of changes. I have read that GIT is a good tool, although I'm not sure whether this is still good for a solo worker (I don't collaborate on any code).

My current method of versioning is that I have a sub folder included in my path that houses all my subfunctions. My scripts are in the current working folder. Whenever I decide to make a radical change (cleaning up redundant files, merging functions together, breaking functions into smaller functions, etc.) i.e. trying to get things more organized, I copy the whole working folder contents into some archive called, for example, "Version3", and then continue on making changes in my current working folder. Is this something that could be better managed using GIT?

Also, how does GIT handle things if I want to change a function from say

```
function T = datatableimport(fileName)
```

to something like

```
function T = datatableimport(fileName, lowerDateLimit, upperDateLimit)
```

where the contents and arguments of `datatableimport` are different? This would presumably break the code in older scripts that use the function. Would it be better to make a new function instead called:

```
function T = datatableimportnew(fileName, lowerDateLimit, upperDateLimit)
```

and keep the old one in a 'legacy' folder, so that things continue to work? I'm just unsure about the best way to go about organizing and handling such circumstances is, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since matlab does not support method polymorphism, you'll have to give the new function a different name.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [As a sole developer (for now), how should I be using Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114258/64132)

Comment: @RobertHarvey is correct, but this problem of changing function arguments has nothing to do with Git. Git can save and restore snapshots of your code, but it doesn't magically prevent you from writing inconsistent code. If you change the required parameters for a function, it's up to you to fix all the places where the function is called. One thing you might look into is [functions that accept a variable number of arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html;jsessionid=1e34839a6ecfcb46260454a1c918).

Comment: *git* gives you the possibility to collect dependend changes in different files in a single commit. But your IDE must support this dependent changes in the first place (i.e. by automated refactorings). If your IDE does not have that you have to do a full compile before each commit your own...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle would you say that MATLAB'sGIT integration is decent? Or is it buggy? Or is it worth using?

Comment: If you wan't to catch this the standard approach is to setup a build server that builds and tests when ever there is a new commit. If this is overkill in this case you could consider a post commit hook that computer after commit.

Comment: @teepee I don't know MATLAB nor its git integration. But as I wrote, git may not be able to solve your problem. I support Esben Skov Pedersens suggestion to set up a build server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NB: The question asked specifically mentions git, but the question could probably apply to version control generally, so I've tried to write a generic answer, although it certainly applies to git.*

The problems solved by [Version Control Systems (VCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) apply equally to developers working on their own as in a team;  the only difference between a solo developer and a team of developers is that the consequences of a whole team working without version control tend to be far more chaotic and time consuming.

I'd personally suggest to any software developer that they should **always** keep their work under version control (Git is a good choice), as it generally costs nothing in terms of time and effort (often saves time in fact), yet the risks of not using version control tend to be substantial in terms of the amount of time and effort needed when you discover a mistake or need to juggle multiple different tasks at the same time.

> My current method of versioning is that I have a sub folder included in my path that houses all my subfunctions. My scripts are in the current working folder. Whenever I decide to make a radical change (cleaning up redundant files, merging functions together, breaking functions into smaller functions, etc.) i.e. trying to get things more organized, I copy the whole working folder contents into some archive called, for example, "Version3", and then continue on making changes in my current working folder. Is this something that could be better managed using GIT?

In a VCS, you would stop all of this copy+pasting and instead keep your main code in a "master" [Branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control)) (sometimes called a "trunk" or "root") to act as your main/current-working code line.

If you are implementing a high-risk breaking change that you don't want in your trunk, a typical workflow using version control would be to create a separate *branch* (based on the trunk) to develop and test those changes in isolation until you're finished and feel that it's time to re-integrate.

As far as your basic workflow is concerned, you can approach it in a similar way that you do with your folders, just without making all those unnecessary copies of folders, letting the VCS do the work of figuring out what's changed and when.

The problem with folders is that the only tool you have to manage them is the filesystem on your O/S - they're a blunt instrument.  A folder is a huge snapshot of *everything*; your O/S filesystem probably has no concept of change management or version history.

VCS tools record deltas (i.e. time-stamped changes) known as a [Commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_(version_control)).  At a simplistic level, a VCS is typically a repository of changes-over-time, which you can view and access like a historical timeline, including the fork-points, as well as being able to 'travel' back in time if necessary.

A VCS provides a [Merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)) facility to reintegrate those isolated changes into the master/trunk; merging typically happens when changes in a *branch* are stable (i.e. you've tested them, they seem to work, and are ready to be released).

Alternatively, if you've fixed any bugs or introduced some minor features into the master/trunk since creating the branch, then the merge tool will let you bring those separate branches up-to-date as well.

If you have modified the same code in your *trunk* and your *branch*, then the merge process will attempt to understand changes on both sides (usually simple changes such as whitespace/formatting can be resolved automatically).

Sometimes merge conflicts are complex - for example, you might have deleted a chunk of code in one branch and refactored the same chunk of code in another branch; in which case you've got two contradictory changes, and your human judgement is needed to figure out how to resolve the conflict.

> Also, how does GIT handle things if I want to change a function from
>   say
>
> ```
> function T = datatableimport(fileName)
> ```
>
> to something like
>
> ```
> function T = datatableimport(fileName, lowerDateLimit, upperDateLimit)
> ```
>
> where the contents and arguments of datatableimport are different?
>   This would presumably break the code in older scripts that use the
>   function. Would it be better to make a new function instead called:
>
> ```
> function T = datatableimportnew(fileName, lowerDateLimit, upperDateLimit)
> ```
>
> and keep the old one in a 'legacy' folder, so that things continue to
>   work? I'm just unsure about the best way to go about organizing and
>   handling such circumstances is, and any help would be appreciated.
>   Thanks!

To put it bluntly - git can't really do much to help you here, and there's not really any "right" or "wrong" answer, as it depends on the severity of the change.

You could go and 'fix' the legacy scripts, so long as you're comfortable that it's not going to snowball into a whole mess of changes;  but in many cases, the best thing to do with legacy code is leave it alone and just choose a different name.

---

**Unrelated to the question, but more on maintaining legacy code:**

When you're forced to make changes to legacy code, the best way to protect against breaking something is to ensure that your code is covered by [Automated Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation) where possible - then you can quickly identify when something is broken.

If nothing else, then at least try to work with tools which are able to perform [Static Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) checks, if any are available to you.

Also try to stick with language features which maximise the chance of errors being picked up by the compiler/interpreter, and consider setting up a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) environment to run those tools against your code on a regular basis (e.g. every night).

Comment: This is super super helpful; thank you kindly. I haven't heard much about automated tests but I'll definitely look into it now. I now see more of the benefits of working with GIT, although I am worried about things syncing properly; is it quite robust? I typically work on a desktop on campus and a laptop at home, and all my files are automatically backed up on Google Drive, so I haven't had to worry about it. Will this be just as reliable? And will it allow my files to be synced locally as well as online in a similar way?

Comment: @teepee, modern VCS system are very reliable, but they are quite different from Google Drive or Dropbox. Synching happens when you execute the command for it, not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Version control by itself will not prevent you breaking your code.  But if you use version control properly, it will do is allow you to *back out* of changes that broke your code.

The solution to avoiding breaking your code is testing.  Specifically, implement unit tests and regression tests that you can run at any time.  And run them regularly, and in particular before you check in changed code.

Implementing test suites *looks like* more up-front effort, but the pay-off is that your code-base will have less bugs, and you will pick up newly introduced bugs earlier.

Note that your test code needs to be continually enhanced as your main code grows.  And it needs to be version controlled along with the main code.

---

If you are using version control, then it is a bad idea to keep "legacy" copies of your code in other folders, etc.  The point of version control is that the "legacy" versions are in your version history anyway.  If you need to get a "legacy" version back, just check it out.